# form submission from mail

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a form and send it as a mail. Can I possible to submit that form from gmail.
My form contain an option button and one submit button. When I click the submit button, i will have to store the option button value to the database. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Due to variations between email clients, you can consider `<form>`s in HTML formatted emails to be a no-go area. Link to a form on a website instead.

Comment: "I create a form and send it as a mail" — Don't do this.

Comment: "Can I possible to submit that form from gmail" — Plenty of email systems will prevent it from working. Gmail is probably one of them.

Comment: The answer to your question is "no".